# override key press with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my code, I'm trying to override a keypress (for instance, I'm trying to override all non-numeric keys when a numeric keyboard is displayed). I tried doing the following, and it only worked with the backspace, enter, and tab buttons:

HTML:

```
<input ng-keydown="numberKeydown($event)">
```

JS:

```
$scope.numberKeydown = function(event) {
    if(!(event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) && !(event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)) { // if not 0-9 for normal, numeric keypad
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

None of these worked for me for the punctuation characters (i/e `(` or `)` or `.`, etc). The backspace and enter button now successfully don't work, but the all the other characters still display. I've also tried using `ng-keypress` and `ng-keyup`, though I didn't really expect them to work...

**EDIT**:
I should have mentioned, but I'm doing my testing on a tablet (Nexus 9, iPad)

Comment: a bit easier to read:
```var key = event.keyCode
if (key < 48 || (key > 57 && key < 96) || key > 105) { // if not 0-9 for normal, numeric keypad```

are you sure it's making it inside that block?

Comment: That does make it easier to read! And yes, I can stop the code in that if block (though the behavior acts weird when using breakpoints - I think the timing of events gets messed up)

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle all the required keys as below. Even I handled the number key press with `shift` key which will insert a symbol like `$`.

Also provisioned to allow `Home`, `End`, `Left` & `Right` arrow keys

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.numberKeydown = function(event) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter
    if ([8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 46, 127].indexOf(event.keyCode) !== -1 || 
        // Allow: Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V
        (event.ctrlKey === true && (event.keyCode === 65 || event.keyCode === 67 || event.keyCode === 86)) ||
       // Allow: home, end, left, right
       (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) { 
          return;
      }
    
      // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
      if ((event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57)) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         event.preventDefault();
      }
  };
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="TestController">
   <input ng-keydown="numberKeydown($event)">
</div>
```

Comment: This worked on my laptop.
However, this still doesn't work on a tablet (I'm using a Nexus 9). It blocks all letters, but it doesn't block any punctuation characters. Then, after a punctuation character, I'm then able to type in any letters I want